# Selecting distinct nested relation in Django

Tags: django, orm

To describe the system quickly, I have a list of Orders. Each Order can have 1 to n Items associated with it. Each Item has a list of ItemSizes. Given the following models, which have been abbreviated in terms of fields for this question, my goal is to get a distinct list of ItemSize objects for a given Order object.

```
class ItemSize(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=SIZE_CHOICES)

class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    sizes = models.ManyToManyField(ItemSize)

class OrderItem(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item)

class Order(models.Model):
    some_field = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
```

So... if I have:

```
o = Order.objects.get(id=1)
#how do I use the ORM to do this complex query? 
#i need o.orderitem_set.items.sizes (pseudo-code)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ItemSize.objects.filter(items__orderitems__order=some_order)
```

Assuming you have reverse keys like:

- ItemSize.items - reverse fk for all items with such size
- Item.orderitems - reverse for all orderitems connected to item
- Item.orders - you can guess ;)

(AFAIR that names would be choose by default, but I'm not sure, you have to test it)

More informations about reverse key queries are available in [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships).

Answer (score 3):

In your current set up, the answer by @radious is correct. However, OrderItems really shouldn't exist. Orders should have a direct M2M relationship with Items. An intermediary table will be created much like OrderItems to achieve the relationship, but with an M2M you get much simpler and more logical relations

```
class Order(models.Model):
    some_field = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(Items, related_name='orders')
```

You can then do: `Order.items.all()` and `Item.orders.all()`. The query you need for this issue would be simplified to:

```
ItemSize.objects.filter(item__orders=some_order)
```

If you need additional data on the Order-Item relationship, you can keep OrderItem, but use it as a through table like:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    some_field = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(Items, related_name='orders', through=OrderItem)
```

And you still get your simpler relationships.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I do have additional fields on the orderitem relationship, so that is the reason for its existence.

Comment: Like I said, even if you keep it, you should use it as a through model with `items` as a ManyToManyField on Order. It'll save a ton of headaches.

Comment: Oh sorry I misunderstood. I'll take a look into doing that. Thanks~